# Moved Craft 3 site to new server and getting "No primary site exists" error

Tags: craft3

I moved a Craft 3 site to a new server. The previous server was a plain vanilla Ubuntu 16 LTS LAMP stack. The new web server is a Bitnami Ubuntu 16 LTS with a LAP stack (no local MySQL). In the new environment I have setup the Craft 3 site to connect to the remote server via SSL. The SSL connection seems to be working fine, but I am getting the following error when I navigate to the site on the new server:

> An Error occurred while handling another error:
>   craft\errors\SiteNotFoundException: No primary site exists in /opt/bitnami/apache2/vhosts/ijm.org/htdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Sites.php:422
>   Stack trace:
>       #0 /opt/bitnami/apache2/vhosts/ijm.org/htdocs/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Request.php(1120): craft\services\Sites->getPrimarySite()

I have tried adding a siteUrl setting in the general.php file, but that didn't help.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this issue by reimporting the database.

Comment: Welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange Shannon, and thanks for returning to post an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else who ends up here - I just got this error while updating a Craft 2 site to 3. I fixed it by running `./craft migrate/all`. Looks like it works in the CLI but not the browser.